# Password match says they don't match when they really do

Tags: php

When entering data it tells password do not match even if they are. What could be wrong with my password confirmation?

```
if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST ['cpassword']){
    array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
}
```

I have tried using the `$_POST` on password and `$_GET` on the `cpassword` and I also tried `$_GET` method on both but to no avail.

Comment: put your form here

Comment: Well, you appear to have a space in `$_POST ['cpassword']`, which would throw a syntax error. Your logic is also stating the two passwords don't match when they do.

Comment: It would make more sense to me to do this on the client side.

Comment: You need to use `!=` instead of `==`. You're script is saying if the two fields match (`==`), throw an error. You need it to actually say if the two fields DO NOT match (`!=`), throw error.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['cpassword']){
   array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
}
```

It check that if password equals (`==`) cpassword, you're throwing the error `The two passwords do not match`. So you are probably doing the opposite of what you want to do. Use the `!==` operator to check if they are **not equal**.

TLDR;
Password == Cpassword , you're giving error do no match even they both matches

Hopefully this enlighten you.

Comment: Thanks guys and sorry for a late response i got it right